# Is there a name for "near the opposite side of the earth"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine the Earth as a perfect hollow sphere. Call the place where you are on its
surface, point A. There is only one place where a line segment that equals the sphere's diameter, or the Earth's diameter in this case, could be located on the opposite side.
What's is the name of that opposite point furthest from me?
ans:Antipode

I am looking for a word which specifies "nearly at the ellipsoid opposite side of the earth", by which I mean, given a beam that is perpendicular to earth surface at a given first location, and the second location that this beam crosses earth on the other end, what is a word that specifies a place that is near the second location?

Comment: Add a drawing please?

Comment: @mplungjan You gave the answer I was expecting and the drawings on their site are much better than the ones I could produce at the moment so I'm just going to refrain from trying to draw a ball and a beam going through it in gimp :-)

Comment: Helpful website at http://www.proximitycast.com/tools/AntipodeCalculator.php . At Wolfram Alpha, you may type in the name of a city (e.g., http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=buenos+aires&lk=4&num=1), and it will give you coordinates. To find the antipode, flip the N/S on latitude and add or subtract 180 and flip the longitude between E and W. You can also ask Wolfram Alpha for the city at that site (which most often will be ocean).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Antipodes comes to mind

[Wikipedia - antipodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodes)

> Two points that are antipodal to each other are connected by a straight line running through the centre of the Earth.
>
> ...
>
> The antipodes of any place on the Earth is the place that is diametrically opposite it, so a line drawn from the one to the other passes through the centre of the Earth and forms a true diameter. For example, the antipodes of New Zealand's lower North Island lies in Spain. Most of the Earth's land surfaces have ocean at their antipodes, this being a consequence of most land being in the land hemisphere.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a slight anomaly, though. In the sense of *the region on the Earth's surface which is diametrically opposite to another region,* the term is *Antipodes*, singular, **with the trailing s**, but some dictionaries list *antipode* as singular and *antipodes* as plural. Cf. 'The **antipodes** of any place on the Earth **is** the place ...' above.

Comment: Fixed. I got the singular via antipodean. so one antipode, two antipodes sounded logical - I always assumed that the plural came from the two places that are each other's antipode

Comment: Sure. I just still assumed the SET of TWO points were the antipodes :)

Comment: Compare: an·tip·o·des (n-tp-dz) pl.n. 1. Any two places or regions that are on diametrically opposite sides of the earth. TFD thefreedictionary.com/antipodes --> In geography, the term is *antipodes* sing., I believe.

Comment: Antipodes are a plot point in *The Blessing*, the last episode of *Torchwood: Miracle Day*, involving Captain Jack Harkness, Buenos Aires, and Shanghai.

Comment: [Wiktionary notes that "antipodes" is is a plural-only word](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antipodes), like "scissors" or "pants".